# Emacs: import a CSV into org-mode

Tags: emacs, csv, import, org-mode

Emacs has a very nice extension by the name of org-mode.

I would like to be able to easily load CSV files into org-mode without significant grief. All I've been able to find is table-import or table-capture, which, simply put, don't work even approximately well.

Note that part of my issue is text strings with a comma within them.  1,2,3,4 is different than 1,2,"3,4".

Is there a function out there or a perl script that one could run to transform a csv file into org-mode format?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look if http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ by Neil Butterworth. It has CSV->XML conversion, so maybe you could use that as a part of the solution.

Comment: Only partly related, but still worthwhile reading for anyone who isn't already aware of the number of edge cases CSV presents: https://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/

Answer (score 91):

From the org-mode manual:

> C-c | Convert the active region to
>   table. If every line contains at least
>   one TAB character, the function
>   assumes that the material is tab
>   separated. If every line contains a
>   comma, comma-separated values (CSV)
>   are assumed. If not, lines are split
>   at whitespace into fields. You can use
>   a prefix argument to force a specific
>   separator: C-u forces CSV, C-u C-u
>   forces TAB, and a numeric argument N
>   indicates that at least N consecutive
>   spaces, or alternatively a TAB will be
>   the separator. If there is no active
>   region, this command creates an empty
>   Org table.

So just paste the data into an org file, select it, and do `C-u C-c |` .

Comment: Hmm, looks like the "fi" ligatures in the PDF got dropped out of the quote above... anyway... "elds" should be "fields," "specic" should be "specific," and "prex" should be "prefix."

Comment: Doesn't work when you have CSV fields that contain commas, which the OP specifies...

Comment: Even the auto-detect (without leading C-u) works fine for CSV with embedded commas in the (quoted) values.

Comment: Just in case (like me) your key bindings are screwed up and C-u C-c | is not working, the direct function to call (after selecting a region to convert) is *M-x org-table-convert-region*

Comment: @DonWomick This does not work if the data has commas and newlines wrapped in double quotes: `a,b,c,"def, <newline> ghi"`

Comment: The above comment is right, unless I am missing something. @DonWomick 's answer does not answer the OP's question about commas and newlines wrapped in quotes. How can I convert to a table when there are commas/newlines wrapped in quotes for my csv fields?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at:

`C-h f org-table-convert-region`

I'm always converting csv so I added this to my .emacs.

```
(defun org-convert-csv-table (beg end)
  (interactive (list (mark) (point)))
  (org-table-convert-region beg end ",")
  )

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
    (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") 'org-convert-csv-table)))
```

*update*

Here is another function that considers the quoted commas as well :

```
 a,"12,12",b --> a | 12,12 |b
```

feel free to improve it :-).

```
(defun org-convert-csv-table (beg end)
  ; convert csv to org-table considering "12,12"
  (interactive (list (point) (mark)))
  (replace-regexp "\\(^\\)\\|\\(\".*?\"\\)\\|," (quote (replace-eval-replacement
                            replace-quote (cond ((equal "^" (match-string 1)) "|")
                                                   ((equal "," (match-string 0)) "|")
                                                   ((match-string 2))) ))  nil  beg end)
```

Comment: Tried your function, every line starts with `nil` and quotes often stay on

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you want to convert your CSV specifically into org-mode **tables**. If that's not the case, you may want to be more explicit about output format in your question.

Something like this should do it, or at least get you a starting point you can hack on:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use Text::CSV;

  my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

  while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if ( $csv->parse( $line )) {
      my $str = join '|' , $csv->fields();
      print "|$str|\n";
    }
  }


  __DATA__
  1,2,3,4
  1,2,"3,4"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
;; Insert a file and convert it to an org table
(defun aleblanc/insert-file-as-org-table (filename)
  "Insert a file into the current buffer at point, and convert it to an org table."
  (interactive (list (ido-read-file-name "csv file: ")))
  (let* ((start (point))
    (end (+ start (nth 1 (insert-file-contents filename)))))
    (org-table-convert-region start end)
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of a hack-job, but it works.

when you export the CSV file, force quotes around each entry, then replace all `","` as a vertical bar.

Finally, I make a macro that does something like this:

```
C-a    ; Beginning-of-line
|      ; Self-insert-char
C-e    ; end-of-line
|      ; Self-insert-char
<down> ; Down one line
```

(I am not 100% sure if | is a self-insert-char or not, so its best to record your own macro)

Hit tab somewhere in the middle of the table, and org-mode formats it properly. I find this easier to do in a narrowed region.

Caveat:  If you have a vertical bar in your input.. it probably won't work quite right. Situations like that should be easy to spot, and relatively easy to fix.

Generally, when importing something text-like into org-mode, I have found a combination of some smart macro writing, and search-replace to be the easiest way

I hope that helps.